# Why doesn't RubyMine 2018.2 detect my gems?

Tags: ruby, bundler, zsh, rubymine, rbenv

I'm trying to debug a Rails project within RubyMine v2018.2 (2018.2.1, 2018.2.4).  When I start the editor I get a warning:

> RubyMine Gem Manager: RubyMine has detected that some of the gems required for '*project*' are not installed.

When I try to run RubyMine's Bundler install command I'm told

```
bash -c "RBENV_VERSION=2.5.0 /usr/bin/rbenv exec bundle install -V"
Activating bundler (< 2) failed:
Could not find 'bundler' (< 2) among 28 total gem(s)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/brad/.gem/ruby/2.5.0:/var/lib/gems/2.5.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.5.0:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.5.0:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all', execute `gem env` for more information

To install the version of bundler this project requires, run `gem install bundler -v '< 2'`
```

...and when I try to run or debug my application from the IDE I'm told "Could not find bundler (*version*) required by your *project-path*/Gemfile.lock."

Why doesn't RubyMine detect my installed Gems?

### My environment

- Ubuntu 18.04.01
- zsh 5.4.2
- rbenv 1.0.0
- rbenv-binstubs @ 8ecb7ca8
- Rubymine 2018.2.4

I'm using rbenv to manage my Ruby versions.  The system has Ruby 2.5.1 installed, but my project depends on 2.5.0.  I've set 2.5.0 as the rbenv global version. Configuration for [how rbenv chooses a Ruby version](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version) seems okay; I get the following results from the noninteractive commands:

```
> echo $RBENV_VERSION
(no response)

> cat ~/.rbenv/version
2.5.0

> rbenv global
2.5.0
```

After noticing rbenv wasn't working properly in some RubyMine commands I moved the `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` setup step from by `~/.zshrc` up to `~/.zshenv` and `~/.profile` so it will also apply to bash and zsh login shells (per guidance [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/unix-shell-initialization)).  I'm now getting matching results for interactive and login shells, but still getting unexpected behavior from the Bundle install command within RubyMine.

### What is working

My application installs, builds and runs just fine from an interactive shell.

RubyMine's Ruby SDK settings correctly detect rvm and its installed versions, and all of the installed gems for that version.

[image: RubyMine Ruby SDK Settings]

### What I've tried

The output from the bundle install command claims it's running

```
bash -c "RBENV_VERSION=2.5.0 /usr/bin/rbenv exec bundle install"
```

When I run this from my interactive shell or with RubyMine's "Run anything" feature (login shell) this command works fine - as does any of the following:

```
RBENV_VERSION=2.5.0 /usr/bin/rbenv exec bundle install
/usr/bin/rbenv exec bundle install
rbenv exec bundle install
bundle install
```

So I can't figure out what context RubyMine is using to run this command.  It's clear from the error message that the `GEM_PATH` is incorrect, causing RubyMine to look in the wrong place for bundler, but I don't know where it's getting this configuration.  If I bring up the "RubyGems Environment" view in RubyMine I get:

```
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.3
RUBY VERSION: 2.5.0 (2017-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/brad/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/brad/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/brad/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/ruby
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/brad/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin
SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/brad/.gem/specs
SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/brad/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/etc
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  ruby
  x86_64-linux
GEM PATHS:
   /home/brad/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
   /home/brad/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
(...)
SHELL PATH:
   /home/brad/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin
   /usr/lib/rbenv/libexec
   /home/brad/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
   /home/brad/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gemset/bin
   /home/brad/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-binstubs/bin
   (...rest of PATH...)
----------------------
IDE: RubyMine 2018.2.4, build #RM-182.4505.55
OS: Linux 4.15.0-38-generic[amd64]
Java: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8
RubyMine SDK Environment:
Sdk: rbenv: 2.5.0
Sdk Version: ver.2.5.0p0 ( revision 61468) p0
Ruby Interpreter: /home/brad/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/ruby
RVM Sdk: Rbenv sdk, gemset nullSdk Language Level: 2.5
Sdk Load Path:
     ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.2.0/lib
     ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0
     ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-linux
     ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby
     ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.5.0
     ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-linux
     ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
     ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0
     ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-linux
     ~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/RubyMine/ch-0/182.4505.55/rubystubs25
Sdk Gem paths: 
     ~/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems
     ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems
     ~/.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems
     ~/.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems
     ~/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems
     ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems
(full list of gems used for project)
```

So I think that last bit - "Sdk Gem paths" - might be the problem point, but I don't see any way to configure it.

I'm also already aware of the YouTrack issue ["Rubymine 2018.2 release does not take $GEM_HOME environment variable"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-22237) and don't think it's quite what's happening here.  It also claims to be fixed in 2018.3 EAP1, so I installed 2018.3 EAP7 but am still seeing this problem.

Comment: Your answer might be found among this text: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version . Have you tried setting the global rbenv version, to make sure rbenv is picking the right executable?

Comment: Yes; I'm only setting the global rbenv version (see edits in post).  I'm seeing different results for `which gem` and `rbenv which gem` suggesting the shims aren't applying to RubyMine.  Likewise, `which bundle/bundler` is no longer finding anything, while `rbenv which bundle/bundler` is finding the correct versions.

Comment: Perhaps you want to open a new issue with RubyMine instead. If you figure it out post the answer here too. The things that influence executable and gem selections are PATH and the GEM_* variables. Both need to be the same in order for the right executables and gems to be found. But you have a lot of moving parts here, making it difficult to debug without access to your console. Rbenv in itself is already a complex piece of code, and you have binstubs added on top also.

Comment: Thanks! I just opened a support ticket, and will describe the results here. In the meantime I'll do more investigation of those two environment variables.

Comment: I did some hunting for the environment variables you mentioned and found a couple of things.  First, I don't see GEM_* set anywhere.  Second, my zsh login shell PATH is missing a couple of entries when run inside RubyMine: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.0/bin and (!) ~/.rbenv/shims. The next question is -why-.  Exploration documented here: https://gist.github.com/islemaster/6fa6abb0a7386de2277b1d605f6ef53a

Comment: I think you might be on the right track. Note that GEM_* does not HAVE to be set anywhere. Rbenv will set it when you run it most likely. This is what I mean by layers of complexity. But that the shims path is missing seems relevant to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got things working!  By signing out and back in. :facepalm:

To be specific, I *think* the key steps were

1. Move the `$(rbenv init -)` step from my `.zshrc` up to my `.zshenv` and/or to `.profile`
2. Signing out and back in.

The key insight was noticing that `~/.rbenv/shims` was missing from the RubyMine Gem Environment despite showing up in both interactive and login shells (in and out of RubyMine), and realizing that while *new* shells were picking up my `.profile` changes, RubyMine itself was probably inheriting its environment variables from my session and I'd need to log out/in to to pick up the changes.

I now see `~/.rbenv/shims` in my RubyMine Gem Environment, and both the Bundler Install command and my run configurations are working again.

Thank you [Casper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823617/casper) for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: The old "have you turned it off and on again" :)

Comment: Thanks for this excellent explanation. Put an end to a long hair-pulling session.

Answer (score 2):

Been where you are before a bunch of times.

Under the list of scripts you can run, click "Edit Configurations". Should be in the main toolbar.

[image: edit configuration]

Double check that you have "Run the script in context of bundle (bundle exec)" checked on the bundler tab. This is SUPER important and is not checked by default. Make sure you check for any rake, rails or irb configurations.

[image: bundler context]

Keep in mind that the run configuration is where you can override the settings for the project. It will create all kinds of problems if this is not set appropriately.

[image: project SDK]

Hope this helps! Bit me a bunch of times.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!  I have also had to set these in the past. Unfortunately this doesn't solve my situation, probably because RubyMine can't find Bundler at all.  I've checked `bundle exec` and manually set the SDK for all of my run configurations, but I'm seeing this problem with tools that aren't tied to run configurations at all, such as "Tools > Bundler > Install."